# How to assign a class to the last element rendered by template for: each

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I would like to assign a class in javascript to the last element rendered by template for: each. The content is wired from the server, everything is displayed correctly but I don't know how to assign class to the last item

```
   connectedCallback() {
    getBrand().then((data) => {
      this.brands = data;
      if (this.brands) {
        this.template.querySelector('.brands>li:last-child').classList.add('class')
      }
    });
  }

    
      <ul class="brands">
        <template for:each={brands} for:item="el">
          <li class="brands__container" key={el.id}>
            <a href="" data-nexttab={test} class="indexable">
              <img src={el.Image__c} class="brands-image" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </template>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of these two ways depending on your context:

- Use the correct css selector to directly apply the styling to the last element
- Use a property `classNames` on your items to set the classes of the DOM element

Using a css selector is probably lighter but as said if you're in a complex situation like toggling state or else, js will probably give you a better control.